# Dentistry: Salt water rinse 30 minutes before bleach rinse?

Tags: dentistry

There is a lot of consensus online about the many benefits of a salt water rinse [1].

Recently, a lot of consensus has emerged about the benefits of a diluted bleach rinse [2].

**Is there any reason why one would not do a bleach rinse approximately 30 minutes after a salt water rinse?**

For example, my dentist says not to do both bleach rinse and another chemical rinse, Opti-Rinse, because of the lack of awareness of possible interactions.  I just reached out to the makers of Opti-Rinse for advice (response pending).  I cannot reach out to a specific manufacturer of salt or bleach about possible interactions because they are such generic things.  Neither can I find anything about their combined use from an [online search](https://www.google.com/search?q=salt-water+dilute+bleach+rinse+dental).

The question complicated by the passage of time.  Many rinses say to wait 30 minutes before eating/drinking, but I don't know what this means in terms of whether most residue is gone above the gum line or below the gum line.  I would be interested in residue fading time below the gum line.  Answering this question seems to me to be a matter of dental expertise and experience.  That's assuming that there is any possible interaction to be on guard against.

**Notes**

[1] For an example of advice about rinsing with saline, see [this](https://www.healthline.com/health/dental-and-oral-health/salt-water-rinse) page, or more generally, [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=salt-water+rinse+dental) search phrase.

[2] For an example of advice about rinsing with diluted bleach, see [this](https://www.speareducation.com/spear-review/2017/10/mouthrinsing-with-bleach-a-promising-alternative-to-chlorhexidine) page, or more generally, [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=dental+rinse+dilute+bleach) search phrase.

Comment: What has your research revealed so far?

Comment: There are many trials with with bleach, ranging from 0.05% to 0.25% sodium hypochlorite from bleach. More than 2x/week can cause staining. Most online info laud salt water rinse. These are empirical. Nothing about using them in combination.  For most rinses other than saline, you should wait 30-60 minutes before eating.  Nothing about how long to wait after saline rinse before a chemical rinse.

Comment: Got it, but questions are required to show some effort at prior research, so all you have to do is add an example of those findings.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Warm saline rinses are recommended for maintaining oral hygiene, and post dental procedure.
[Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/sj.bdj.2009.1093)

> Warming the water and adding a pinch of table salt to it can enhance its efficacy to a great extent. It can reduce or even be an alternative to anti-inflammatory drugs intra-orally. Its high osmolality reduces inflammation and can be microbicidal. Warm saline rinses have been used successfully in post extraction cases. We have also been using it in post surgical periodontal cases for many years and the results have been excellent.

Talking about rinsing with bleach-[Here](https://www.speareducation.com/spear-review/2017/10/mouthrinsing-with-bleach-a-promising-alternative-to-chlorhexidine)

> A randomized control trial comparing the effects of swishing twice a week with 0.25-percent sodium hypochlorite (vs water) in addition to a person’s oral hygiene routine showed statistically significant improvements in plaque-free surfaces and the number of sites with bleeding on probing after three months. The only reported side effects had to do with the taste of the rinse itself.

Now introducing a term **Substantivity** which [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substantivity#:%7E:text=substantivity%20(plural%20substantivities),to%20stick%20to%20a%20target.)

> The ability of a chemical or dye to stick to a target.

Chemicals have different substantivities. Depending on their substantivities,
the companies recommend a time range to consume an eatable or a beverage, and not following the same, i.e. consuming something before the recommended time, will hamper the mechanism of action of that chemical on the tooth surface, that chemical won't be able to perform the function which it intends to, as now that chemical is no more attached to the tooth surface, due to the interruption from a food particle, or some other chemical before its substantivity.
For example, a popular mouth-wash [chlorhexidine](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030057121000076X)

[image: Here]

Comment: Thank you for the information, Ojasvi.  It's interesting, especially substantivity.  It doesn't address my question about interactivity of diluted bleach rinse 30  minutes after salt water rinse, but I suspect that the question is quite specific about the timing and combining of specific rinses.  I fear that there is no information on this yet.